# PhpStorm relative path to resource root

Tags: html, angularjs, polymer, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm 9 and I have project structure similar to this:

```
src/
   elements/
      element-alfa/
         element-alfa.html
         element-alfa.scss
   templates/
      application.html
   index.html
```

I use [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) so I have to import the elements when I use them. I also use AngularJS, which direct the app after load to **application.html**, but in fact paths are like from the **index.html** file.

```
<link rel="import" href="elements/element-alfa/element-alfa.html">
```

I have set the **src/** directory as **RESOURCES ROOT** so it does not tinged the background color under href path but if I use auto hint (*CTRL + 2x SPACE*), it returns the path *relative to the file application.html*, **not relative to the index.html (or my resources root)** as I wanted to.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Of course, what you're asking for is incorrect from the point of standard HTML. If that's a Polymer requirement (no idea), no IDE will ever do it unless it has a specific plug-in.

Comment: I do not think so. It knows how to do **resources root** which add ability to understand the path from modified path so why it would not have ability to make hint from this path? :)

Comment: Because it needs to know your HTML is a *template* that will *not* load from `templates` from the browser point of view? ;-P

Comment: I do understand now. Well, it would be nice to have the ability to set "do things like you are the index.html file"... :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to do it is to type/autocomplete each folder one by one sequentially: first `elements`, then `element-alfa`, and then autocomplete filename. I created a feature request about this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30888