# IntelliJ IDEA / PhpStorm "Cannot resolve directory" for PHP project

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

**Situation:** I have the following PHP project structure:

```
/images    (contains images)
/views     (contains .blade.php template files)
/vendor
composer.json
index.php
```

In a template I have an `<img src="images/challenges/week3-food.jpg" />`.

**Problem:** IDEA marks "images" with a warning, saying "Cannot resolve directory 'images'".

**Elaboration:** If I press `Alt+Enter`, "Create Directory images", it creates an "images" folder under my `/views` folder.

**My goal:** I want IDEA to understand that my project root is my webroot, and find my files there. Basically, I want the warning gone and code completion work for my paths.

**What I tried:** I went to `File --> Project Structure --> Modules` and set my project root as Resource Root, with no luck.

**Screenshot:** http://screencast.com/t/33mV4umA

Any advice on how to achieve this? I have had this issue on several other projects.

Comment: Is the folder structure you listed in `public` or `resources`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I am only using Laravel's Blade templating engine, otherwise it's vanilla PHP. What I listed is the project root. I have corrected my question accordingly.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Basically, you should add a `/` before the path.

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you are doing `images/challenges/week3-food.jpg` but should be `/images/challenges/week3-food.jpg` (the slash in the beginning of the file path).

So it would be

```
<img src="/images/challenges/week3-food.jpg" />
```

PHPStorm should be able to read this as it should be in the `images` directory of the root folder.

Comment: Switching to absolute references as you suggested would bind me to running the site in the server root. But I need to deploy it in a subfolder (`example.com/photo-challenge/`) so it is not an option for me. Any other suggestion which does not involve changing the code?

Comment: You can do `<img src="../../images/challenges/week3-food.jpg" />` if you want to use relative paths. You can always make a helper method just like Laravel's own `url()` helper method which can take a parameter and return the URL with a base path. So you would only do something like `url(images/yourimage)`.

Comment: `<img src="../../images/challenges/week3-food.jpg" />` clearly does not work, because it's the wrong path relative to `index.php`.
`url()` might help, yes, but I'd rather not include Laravel in my project just for this. Is there really no way to instruct IntelliJ about my resources root?

Comment: With `url()`, you don't have to use Laravel for this. You can write your own function which can be accessed by all your blade files if you autoload a helper file containing `url()` with composer. As long as the project root folder goes, you have already specified your project root folder when you created a new project.

Comment: Thanks Taylor; Your answer did not give me a solution, but it cleared up my real issue. My problem is basically a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317048/phpstorm-relative-path-to-resource-root